# Javascript class to geocode Dutch addresses

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, async-await, promise, geospatial

I am relatively new to javascript ES6, the code I've written is working fine. However I am curious if this would be the best approach. I am trying to write a reusable module that I can use in multiple projects. On top of an API I've written a simple module to geocode adresses in the Netherlands. The suggest function will provide related adresses to a specific query. The lookup function provides information about a specific adress.

```
class Geocoder {
    // Class to geocode adresses to coordinates or find related adresses
    // suggest(), lookup() both return a promise
    // geocoder.lookup('adr-54e85361e27f833dd8331fd85bc46ac6').then((data) => {console.log(data)});

    constructor() {
        this.url = "https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/locatieserver/v3/";
    }

    async suggest(query) {
        let url = `${this.url}suggest?q=${query}`;
        return await this._get(url);
    }

    async lookup(id) {
        let url = `${this.url}lookup?id=${id}`;
        return await this._get(url);
    }

    _get(url) {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(url).then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            }).then((json) => {
                resolve(json);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            })    
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe code is in an early stage then...let me ask before answering: 1) what's the added value of `this._get(something)` over `fetch(something)`?  You're just _saving_ that `.then(response => response.json())`. 2) what do you need a `class` for? I don't see any encapsulated state, two exported plain functions will work pretty well. 3). What `query` parameter is? I'm lazy to go over geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl specs, why don't you accept an `object` instead of an already encoded query string?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti 1) Indeed, I did that to save a bit of code in order to have cleaner and more readable code in all projects where I use this module. 2) You are right, I don't need class. I guess a good use case for class are multiple instances of something which hold their own separate state? 3) The parameter is a string, I don't really understand what you mean. That I take an object as input and create a string of it in my suggest / lookup function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Promise` when `async`/`await` is supported is a sign of an anti-pattern. The only case you ever manually build promise in an environment that supports `async`/`await` is when the asynchronous operation cannot be written linearly/when you can't `await` (e.g. `resolve` must be called in a callback).

```
// You cannot really "await" this kind of API, hence the wrapper Promise.
foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject){
    someAPIThatOnlyDoesCallbacks((err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

But in your case, `fetch` returns a promise, `response.json()` also returns a promise. You can just return the promise generated by the whole `fetch` operation itself.

```
_get(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(r => r.json())
}
```

Next, consider using [`Url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [`UrlSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to construct your url. This way, the url is constructed correctly.

```
async suggest(url, param1, param2, ....){
  // Create the url
  const url = new URL(url)

  // Append the values
  url.searchParams.append('param1', param1)
  url.searchParams.append('param2', param2)

  // Construct the url
  return await this._get(url.toString())
}
```

On to other things, there's currently nothing in your class that is instance-specific (the base url is hardcoded, params are supplied at call time). You can simply export a bunch of stateless functions from the module instead of having to instantiate an instance.

```
const getJSON = url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json())
const geocoderUrl = "https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/locatieserver/v3/"

export const suggest = async (query) {
  const url = new URL('suggest', geocoderUrl)
  url.searchParams.append('q', query)
  return await getJSON(url.toString());
}

export const lookup = async(id) => {
  const url = new URL('lookup', geocoderUrl)
  url.searchParams.append('id', id)
  return await getJSON(url.toString());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid code duplication in lookup and suggest functions?